# SQL Foreign Key Errors

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, mysql-error-1064

I am having trouble figuring out the Foreign keys for this database...

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Drop Table
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TJobWorkers' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TJobWorkers
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TWorkerSkills' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TWorkerSkills
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TCustomers' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TCustomers
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TJobMaterials' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TJobMaterials
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TJobs' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TJobs
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TMaterials' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TMaterials
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TSkills' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TSkills
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TStatus' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TStatus
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TWorkers' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TWorkers

IF OBJECT_ID( 'VLaborCosts' )  IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW  VLaborCosts
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Step #1.1: Create Tables
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE TWorkers
(
    intWorkerID                                             INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strFirstName                                           VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strLastName                                            VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,dteHireDate                                            DATE            NOT NULL
    ,monHourlyRate                                          MONEY           NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TWorkers_PK PRIMARY KEY( intWorkerID )
)
CREATE TABLE TStatus
(
    intJobStatusID                                          INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strJobStatus                                           VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TStatus_PK PRIMARY KEY( intJobStatusID )
)
CREATE TABLE TSkills
(
    intSkillID                                              INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strSkillDescription                                    VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TSkills_PK PRIMARY KEY( intSkillID )
)
CREATE TABLE TMaterials
(
    intMaterialID                                           INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strMaterialName                                        VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,monMatieralCost                                        MONEY           NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TMaterials_PK PRIMARY KEY( intMaterialID )
)
CREATE TABLE TJobs
(
    intJobID                                                INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intJobStatusID                                         INTEGER         NOT NULL    
    ,strJobDescription                                      VARCHAR(2000)   NOT NULL
    ,dteStartDate                                           DATE            NOT NULL
    ,dteEndDate                                             DATE            NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TJobs_PK PRIMARY KEY( intJobID )
)
CREATE TABLE TJobMaterials
(
    intMaterialID                                           INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intJobID                                               INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intMaterialQuantity                                    INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TJobMaterials_PK PRIMARY KEY( intJobID,intMaterialID )
)
CREATE TABLE TCustomers
(
    intCustomerID                                           INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intJobID                                               INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strFirstName                                           VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strLastName                                            VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strAddress                                             VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strCity                                                VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strState                                               VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strZipCode                                             VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TCustomers_PK PRIMARY KEY( intJobID )
)
CREATE TABLE TWorkerSkills
(
    intWorkerID                                             INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intSkillID                                             INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TWorkerSkills_PK PRIMARY KEY( intWorkerID,intSkillID )
)
CREATE TABLE TJobWorkers
(
    intJobID                                                INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intWorkerID                                            INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intTotalHoursWorkedByWorker                            INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TJobWorkers_PK PRIMARY KEY( intJobID,intWorkerID )
)
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Step #1.2: Create foreign key constraints to enforce referential integrity for all relationships.
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

ALTER TABLE TWorkers ADD CONSTRAINT TWorkers_TWorkerSkills_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intWorkerID ) REFERENCES TWorkerSkills ( intWorkerID )

ALTER TABLE TStatus ADD CONSTRAINT TStatus_TJobs_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intJobStatusID ) REFERENCES TJobs ( intJobStatusID )

ALTER TABLE TSkills ADD CONSTRAINT TSkills_TWorkerSkills_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intSkillID ) REFERENCES TWorkerSkills ( intSkillID )

ALTER TABLE TMaterials ADD CONSTRAINT TMaterials_TJobMaterials_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intMaterialID ) REFERENCES TJobMaterials ( intMaterialID )

ALTER TABLE TJobs ADD CONSTRAINT TJobs_TJobMaterials_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intJobID ) REFERENCES TJobMaterials ( intJobID )

ALTER TABLE TCustomers ADD CONSTRAINT TJobs_TCustomers_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intJobID ) REFERENCES TJobs ( intJobID )

ALTER TABLE TJobs ADD CONSTRAINT TJobs_TJobWorkers_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intJobID ) REFERENCES TJobWorkers ( intJobID )
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Step #2.1: Populate each table with test data. Make sure that you have sufficient 
--            data to test all indicated Updates, Deletes, and Queries.
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO TWorkers (intWorkerID,strFirstName,strLastName,dteHireDate,monHourlyRate)
VALUES      (1,'Mark','Anthony','01/01/2014',15.00)
            ,(2,'Sam','Bradford','02/01/2014',25.00)
            ,(3,'Tam','Kim','03/01/2014',10.00)
            ,(4,'Bill','Tull','04/01/2015',17.00)
            ,(5,'Mill','Patty','05/01/2015',18.00)
            ,(6,'Sill','Hill','06/01/2014',13.00)
            ,(7,'Cam','Newton','07/01/2015',12.00)
            ,(8,'Pam','Van','08/01/2015',30.00)
            ,(9,'Fam','Cham','09/01/2014',19.00)
            ,(10,'Kam','Kimer','10/01/2015',15.00)

INSERT INTO TStatus (intJobStatusID,strJobStatus)
VALUES      (1,'Open')
            ,(2,'In Progress')
            ,(3,'Complete')

INSERT INTO TSkills (intSkillID,strSkillDescription)
VALUES      (1,'Planner')
            ,(2,'Sander')
            ,(3,'Painting')
            ,(4,'Drawing')
            ,(5,'Hammering')
            ,(6,'Climbing')
            ,(8,'Gaming')
            ,(9,'Talking')
            ,(10,'Eating')
            ,(11,'Sleeping')
            ,(12,'Hitting')
            ,(13,'Fighting')
            ,(14,'Rapping')
            ,(15,'Singing')
            ,(16,'Learning')
            ,(17,'Running')
            ,(18,'Walking')
            ,(19,'Standing')
            ,(20,'Nailing')

INSERT INTO TMaterials (intMaterialID,strMaterialName,monMatieralCost)
VALUES      (1,'Wood',100)
            ,(2,'Stone',100)
            ,(3,'Concrete',50)
            ,(4,'Diamond',10000)
            ,(5,'Silver',1000)
            ,(6,'Iron',1050)
            ,(7,'Gold',3000)
            ,(8,'Titanium',400)
            ,(9,'Trantanium',200)
            ,(10,'Paint',20)
            ,(11,'Morter',20)
            ,(12,'Unobtanium',100000)

INSERT INTO TJobs (intJobID,intJobStatusID,strJobDescription,dteStartDate,dteEndDate)
VALUES      (1,1,'Adding a modern Kitchen','01/01/2015','12/01/2015')
            ,(2,2,'Demolishing old barn','02/01/2015','12/01/2015')
            ,(3,3,'Adding on a Master closet','03/01/2015','03/30/2015')
            ,(4,1,'Remodeling bedrooms','04/01/2015','12/01/2015')
            ,(5,2,'Repaving driveway','05/01/2015','12/01/2015')
            ,(6,1,'Painting hallway','06/01/2015','09/01/2015')
            ,(7,2,'Repaving street','05/01/2014','12/01/2014')
            ,(8,2,'Painting bedroom','06/01/2014','09/01/2014')

INSERT INTO TJobMaterials (intJobID,intMaterialID,intMaterialQuantity)
VALUES      ( 1 , 1 , 1 )
            ,( 2 , 2 , 2 )
            ,( 3 , 3 , 2 )
            ,( 4 , 4 , 1 )
            ,( 5 , 5 , 1 )
            ,( 6 , 6 , 2 )
            ,( 7 , 7 , 2 )
            ,( 8 , 8 , 1 )
            ,( 1 , 9 , 3 )
            ,( 2 , 10 , 3 )
            ,( 3 , 11 , 3 )
            ,( 4 , 5 , 1 )
            ,( 5 , 9 , 4 )
            ,( 6 , 9 , 5 )
            ,( 7 , 1 , 6 )
            ,( 8 , 9 , 3 )
            ,( 1 , 7 , 1 )
            ,( 2 , 8 , 1 )
            ,( 3 , 5 , 1 )
            ,( 4 , 11 , 1 )
            ,( 5 , 1 , 2 )
            ,( 1 , 2 , 2 )
            ,( 2 , 3 , 2 )
            ,( 3 , 4 , 2 )

INSERT INTO TCustomers(intCustomerID,intJobID,strFirstName,strLastName,strAddress,strCity,strState,strZipCode)
VALUES      (1,1,'Emily','Bruns','1111 Main Street','West Chester','Ohio','45242')  
            ,(2,2,'Maylen','Jahn','2222 Main Street','Montgomery','Ohio','45243')
            ,(3,3,'Brenna','Schlager','3333 Main Street','Indian Hill','Ohio','45244')
            ,(4,4,'Cara','Roach','4444 Four Rd','Sharonville','Ohio','45245')
            ,(5,5,'Ryan','Roach','5555 Main Street','Cincinnati','Ohio','45246')
            ,(6,6,'Tom','Miller','6666 Orleans Ct','Blue Ash','Ohio','45247')
            ,(6,7,'Tom','Miller','6666 Orleans Ct','Blue Ash','Ohio','45247')
            ,(6,8,'Tom','Miller','6666 Orleans Ct','Blue Ash','Ohio','45247')                                       

INSERT INTO TWorkerSkills (intWorkerID,intSkillID)
VALUES      ( 1 , 1 )
            ,( 2 , 2 )
            ,( 3 , 3 )
            ,( 4 , 4 )
            ,( 5 , 5 )
            ,( 6 , 5 )
            ,( 7 , 1 )
            ,( 8 , 7 )
            ,( 8 , 8 )
            ,( 10 , 9 )
            ,( 1 , 10 )
            ,( 2 , 11 )
            ,( 3 , 12 )
            ,( 4 , 1 )
            ,( 5 , 14 )
            ,( 6 , 15 )
            ,( 1 , 16 )
            ,( 2 , 17 )
            ,( 3 , 18 )
            ,( 1 , 19 )
            ,( 2 , 20 )

INSERT INTO TJobWorkers (intJobID,intWorkerID,intTotalHoursWorkedByWorker)
VALUES      ( 1 , 1 , 0)
            ,( 2 , 2 , 60)
            ,( 3 , 3 , 80)
            ,( 4 , 4 , 10)
            ,( 5 , 5 , 100)
            ,( 6 , 6 , 50)
            ,( 7 , 7 , 150)
            ,( 8 , 8 , 10)
            ,( 3 , 9 , 70)
            ,( 4 , 10 , 75)
            ,( 5 , 7 , 120)
            ,( 6 , 8 , 200)
            ,( 7 , 9 , 19)
            ,( 8 , 10 , 199)
            ,( 7 , 10 , 19)
            ,( 6 , 10 , 193)
```

Every time I run the database these errors are produced for almost every single foreign key...

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'TWorkerSkills' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'TWorkers_TWorkerSkills_FK'.

Any help/revisions/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Your FK constraints are declared the wrong way around, e.g. `TWorkerSkills.intWorkerID` is a subset of and should reference `TWorkers.intWorkerID`.